# "deflect the bark"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Is this to say: where they detract from the right approach or somehow undermine the good effort?

> For Myers and his colleagues, the "very raison d'etre [of psychical research] is the extension of
>   scientific method, of intellectual virtues . . . .into regions where many a current
>   of old tradition, of heated emotion, even of pseudo-scientific prejudice,
>   deflects the bark"

Comment: Hello, inf. This is an off-the-cuff expression, as you will see if you try to Google it and variants. Is there an extended metaphor in play ( ... ... current ... deflects the bark ...)? Does it appear in previous sentences? But as a non-standard usage, it's not a good fit for the ELU template.

Comment: I’m almost certain “bark” here means “ship”, as in “deflects the bark” means “puts the ship off course; leads us astray”. See [Wikipedia on *barques*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barque): one of the alternative spellings is “bark”. (And no, that’s [not a coincidence](https://www.etymonline.com/word/bark?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_5248))

Comment: This is a good comment, @DanBron, and I think it should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Deflect](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/deflect) has a number of usages. The given usage, *deflects the bark* is a metaphor for deflecting criticism.

> If you deflect something such as criticism or attention, you act in a way that prevents it from being directed towards you or affecting you.

Here, a *bark* would be the response of a dog, perhaps lacking intellect or insight; or perhaps in anger. It could be either off-the-cuff or part of a larger context, as @EdwinAshworth suggests.

Comment: Thank you. I now tend to think that the bark in this context is valid scientific criticism that the said prejudices are said to deflect (i.e. uncritically reject), which is to say that Myer's scientific approach is to criticize rather than partake in the said questionable attitudes. Am I right?

Comment: As _current_ is mentioned, it could well be an old word for a boat. See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bark, scrolling down to _noun 3_.

Comment: @KateBunting Right on Kate! The bark is a reference to a tree trunk deflected from the river current by prejudices? Riddle solved?

Comment: A _boat_ deflected from the current.

Comment: @KateBunting To me "bark" as a vessel would automatically mean a 3-masted square-rigger with the mizzen having fore-and-aft sails. I'd never even heard of the "small boat" sense.